# A combinatorics question about selection strategies

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am given a set of balls--red and blue. In each set, there are three kinds of balls--small, medium and large. In each set there are 10 balls of each color:

- 10 Red balls (2 small + 3 medium + 5 large)
- 10 Blue balls (2 small + 3 medium + 5 large).

Now, given **N** sets of balls and **M** balls to be chosen, I've to pick balls in such a way that

- 1) there have to be equal number of red and blue balls
- 2) there have to be equal number of medium and large balls

I think it is a combinatorics question and I thought the answer should be

$2*{3 N \choose M/2}*{5 N \choose M/2}$

But I am not sure of the answer. Please help me. Thanks. :)

Comment: This appears to be the exact same problem as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250256/choosing-m-cards-from-n-decks just a rewording.  Black/Red is replaced here by Blue/Red, and Facecard/Rank is replaced by Medium/Large.  Unfortunately, no answer has been given to that wording either.

Comment: Yes,it certainly looks the same .

Comment: The question is not clear. Are the sets distinguishable or not?

Comment: It seems that boxes are not important. We can assume that all the balls are in the same box. Does anyone disagree?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see a question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a complete answer, but your answer can't be correct. 
Note that if we have chosen the number of small red balls (2N possibilities), the number of small blue balls (2N possibilities) and the number of medium red balls (3N possibilities), we can compute the other values. The number of large red balls can be calculated by substracting the other red balls form $M/2$. Then te number of blue medium and large balls can be calculated. However, not every triple of balls gives a solution.

The total number of balls must be even and the total number of medium+large balls must be even too. Therfore the number of small balls must be even. This gives only N possibilities for the number of small blue balls once the number of small red balls is chosen.

This gives the bound:

$$\text{number of possibilities} < 6N^3$$

For M=10, N=5 your answer gives 319098780, while my bound gives only 750. However, I have no idea how to finish it.